# SVG icon changes when SVG sprite set to display:none

Tags: css, svg

If I embed an SVG sprite

```
<svg class="hidden-svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="208px" height="104px" viewBox="0 0 34 34" enable-background="new 0 0 34 34" xml:space="preserve" >
   <g id="phone2">
      .....
   </g>
 </svg>
```

and reference an embedded icon as follows:

```
<svg viewBox="1 1 32 32" class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#phone2"></use>
</svg>
```

If is set the SVG sprite to:

```
.hidden-svg {
  display: none;  
}
```

It changes the look of my icon.  See [jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/capid/1/edit).

What can I do to avoid changing the icon?

Comment: Use visibility:hidden instead of display:none

Comment: Thank Robert - that is useful.  The only downside is that the original SVG will still take up space in the layout.

Comment: Make it width="0" and height="0" then.

Comment: Doh ... thanks ... that is a good work around.   If your provide that as the answer I'll accept.

Comment: Change to `<g id="phone2" class="hidden-svg">` and it works fine. the root-level element can't be styled, that's like saying `html { display : none; }` Or create a wrapper for the inline svg and set that to not display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use visibility:hidden instead of display:none and make the original SVG width="0" and height="0" so that it doesn't take up space.

Comment: Strangely I found that in Chrome  70.0.3538.110 I had to wrap my SVG with a div with height:0;visibility:hidden to emulate display:none. This fix didn't work for me (browser still rendered around 24px of whitespace), but it pointed me in the right direction